# 'Object reference is required for non-static field' error in console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I am getting the following syntax error in my console app:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.db'

How can I fix this? I've read suggestions about making `db` static, but I don't fully understand that.

```
class Program
{      
    private CallContext db = new CallContext();
    private BreachContext bc = new BreachContext();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var snapshot = db.Calls.Where(x => x.team == "T1").ToList();
```

Comment: What does ASP.Net and ASP.Net MVC has to do with this ? it is just a Console Application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating an instance of `CallContext`, but only when you create an instance of `Program`.

However, `Main` is static and doesn't require an instance of `Program`, so `db` is not instantiated when `Main` runs.

I'd just instantiate it *inside* Main, when you need it. If it's disposable, you might consider wrapping it in a `using` statement as well.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var db = new CallContext();

    var snapshot = db.Calls.Where(x => x.team == "T1").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a good reason to make it a global variable (maybe you use it in other operations too), so if you really want this, the db declaration should be static too:

```
 private static CallContext db = new CallContext();
```

**Reason:** you are using the non-static `db` variable in a static `Main` method, which is not possible.

However, if there is no reason to make it global and static, you can also put the declaration and initialization in the Main method itself and then use it. **I assume** that `CallContext` is an Entity Framework context, so in that case use the `using` statement to dispose it after usage:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
      using (var db = new CallContext())
      {
          var snapshot = db.Calls.Where(x => x.team == "T1").ToList();
      }
 }
```